# Parameters with default value not in PsBoundParameters?

Tags: function, powershell, parameters, powershell-2.0

**General code**

Consider this code:

```
PS> function Test { param($p='default value') $PsBoundParameters }
PS> Test 'some value'
Key                                                               Value
---                                                               -----
p                                                                 some value
PS> Test
# nothing
```

I would expect that `$PsBoundParameters` would contain record for `$p` variable on both cases. Is that correct behaviour?

**Question**

I'd like to use splatting that would work like this for a lot of functions:

```
function SomeFuncWithManyRequiredParams {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$p1,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$p2,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$p3,
  ...other parameters
  )
  ...
}
function SimplifiedFuncWithDefaultValues {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$p1='default for p1',
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$p2='default for p2',
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$p3='default for p3',
  ...other parameters
  )
  SomeFuncWithManyRequiredParams @PsBoundParameters
}
```

I don't want to call SomeFuncWithManyRequiredParams with all the params enumerated:

```
  SomeFuncWithManyRequiredParams -p1 $p1 -p2 $p2 -p3 $p3 ...
```

Is it possible?

Comment: There are two questions I'd have to ask here, for each parameter in question: Why does SomeFunc not have the same default value as SimplifiedFunc? And, if the defaults need to be different, then why does SimplifiedFunc allow the user to override the default (since, in that case, they could simply call SomeFunc directly to override)?

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is very old, but I had a need for something like this recently (wanted to do splatting with a lot of default parameters). I came up with this and it worked very well:

```powershell
$params = @{}
foreach($h in $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters.GetEnumerator()) {
    try {
        $key = $h.Key
        $val = Get-Variable -Name $key -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value -ErrorAction Stop
        if (([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($val) -and (!$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey($key)))) {
            throw "A blank value that wasn't supplied by the user."
        }
        Write-Verbose "$key => '$val'"
        $params[$key] = $val
    } catch {}
}
```

**Shameless plug ahead**: I decided to turn this into a [blog post which has more explanation and a sample usage script](http://www.briantist.com/how-to/splatting-psboundparameters-default-values-optional-parameters/).

Comment: Also see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3285. Beware: this is not correct for dynamic parameters.

Comment: @stijn yeah for sure, none of the workarounds are going to be 100%. It really needs language support and a new alternative to `$PSBoundParameters` is the best idea I think. Either way, it won't make it into Windows PowerShell and there's still a ton of usage of that around so good[enough] workarounds are going to continue to be important.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on how you define "bound" I guess i.e. is the value bound from a user supplied value or a default value supplied by the function?  Honestly, it doesn't surprise me that it behaves the way it does as I view "bound" to mean the former - bound from user input.  Anyway, you can solve this by patching the $PSBoundParameters variable e.g.:

```
function SimplifiedFuncWithDefaultValues { 
  param( 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$p1='default for p1', 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$p2='default for p2', 
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$p3='default for p3', 
  ...other parameters 
  ) 
  if (!$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey(p1))
  {
    $PSBoundParameters.p1 = 'default for p1'
  }
  # rinse and repeat for other default parameters.
  SomeFuncWithManyRequiredParams @PSBoundParameters 
}
```

Comment: Ok, I agree that `$PSBoundParameters` may contain only explicitly supplied arguments, depends on definition. Then there should be a way how to get *all parameters and values* as I have expected.

Comment: Considering the solution you propose: your code is longer than `SomeFuncWithManyRequiredParams -p1 $p1 -p2 $p2 -p3 $p3`. And if all the params in function `SimplifiedFuncWithDefaultValues` have default values then there is no difference, I think.

Comment: I don't see a way of getting the info you want via an automatic variable.  Perhaps you might want to file a MS Connect suggestion.

Comment: FYI, I agree that modifying $PSBoundParameters is more work if every parameter has a default.  I just wanted to point out that it is quite useful to add parameters to this hashtable (as well as remove them) before splatting the variable against the target command.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I like to do:

```
foreach($localP in $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters.Keys)
{
    if(!$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey($localP))
    {
        $PSBoundParameters.Add($localP, (Get-Variable -Name $localP -ValueOnly))
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a helper function similar to the `Add-Variable` function below:

```
function SimplifiedFuncWithDefaultValues {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$p1='default for p1',
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$p2='default for p2',
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$p3='default for p3',
        ...other parameters
    )

    $PSBoundParameters | Add-Variable p1, p2, p3

    SomeFuncWithManyRequiredParams @PSBoundParameters 
}

function Add-Variable {
    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0)]
        [AllowEmptyCollection()]
        [string[]] $Name = @(),
        [Parameter(Position = 1, ValueFromPipeline, Mandatory)]
        $InputObject
    )

    $Name |
    ? {-not $InputObject.ContainsKey($_)} |
    % {$InputObject.Add($_, (gv $_ -Scope 1 -ValueOnly))}
}
```