# Using ValidateScript with custom functions defined later in script

Tags: validation, powershell, parameters, powershell-4.0

Is it possible to use custom functions with `ValidateScript`, where the function is defined later in the script.
Additionally, is it possible to reference other parameters when calling this function (i.e. assuming there's no circular dependency)?

I understand why this may not be possible, but as it's something that would be useful I'm hoping MS implemented some special rule to allow the script to be read and function definitions made available prior to the validation of the parameters occurring.

e.g.

```
#Run-DemoScript.ps1
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$DbInstance 
    ,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$DbCatalog 
    ,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]

    #
    # Is this possible; i.e.
    # - Validate-Country is not defined until later in this script
    # - DbInstance and DbCatalog parameters are defined alongside Country
    [ValidateScript({Validate-Country -Country $_ -DbInstance $DbInstance -DbCatalog $DbCatalog})] 
    #


    [string]$Country
)

#returns $true if the country is in the database's country table; otherwise false
function Validate-Country {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$DbInstance
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$DbCatalog
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$Country
    )
    process {
        $Country = $Country -replace "'","''"
        ((Execute-SQLQuery -DbInstance $DbInstance -DbCatalog $DbCatalog -Query "select top 1 1 x from dbo.Country where Name = '$Country'") | Measure-Object | Select -ExpandProperty Count) -gt 0
    }
}

function Execute-SQLQuery {
    #...
}

"Script ran with Country $Country"
```

**Update**

It seems you can move the whole function definition into the `ValidateScript` attribute, and can still access that function later in the script; e.g:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateScript({
        function IsValid ($test) {
            $test -eq 'test'
        }
        IsValid $_
    })]
    [string]$x
)


"Output: $x"
"Is Valid? $(IsValid $x)"
```

However that's quite painful.  Also it doesn't allow referencing sibling parameters (e.g. below)

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$y
    ,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateScript({
        function IsValid ($a,$b) {
            $a -eq $b
        }
        IsValid $_, $y
    })]
    [string]$x 
)


"X: $x"
"Y: $Y"
"Is Valid? $(IsValid $x $y)"
```

Comment: I'm sure this has already occurred to you but why not just make `Validate-Country` sourced earlier in another "main" script? I completely understand this the necessity of your request though in order to keep this contained.

Comment: Thanks @Matt; yes that's a good solution; I was just hoping to keep the script to a single file to make it easy to share & use with less those technically able (i.e. without having to provide instructions on putting scripts into the same path).

Comment: I understand. Not to distract from your actual issue but you can have a main script call your remote scripts or copy them locally but that does add another level of unneeded level of complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From feedback so far, it seems that doing exactly what I want isn't currently possible in PowerShell v4.

I ended up using a simple workaround to achieve this objective.  It adds a little overhead, but isn't too painful.

1. Removed the `ValidateScript` validation from the file's parameters.
2. Created a new function, `RUN`, and copied the file's parameters exactly to be the parameters for this function.  It doesn't matter where in the script this function appears, so long as it's before it's called (see step 4).
3. Added the `ValidateScript` piece to this function's definition.
4. As the last line of the script called this new `RUN` function passing all parameters (using `@PSBoundParameters` for simplicity / reduced maintenance).
5. Moved all other script logic (excluding function definitions) which could have been placed in the main file to the `process` block of the `RUN` function.
6. Beware the Gotcha: if you use default parameters you'll need to handle these as by default they won't be included in `@PSBoundParameters` mentioned in step 4.  For more info, see [Parameters with default value not in PsBoundParameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808973/parameters-with-default-value-not-in-psboundparameters).  This is not an issue if you copy the default logic to the function definition along with other parameter information.

.

```
#Run-DemoScript.ps1
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$DbInstance 
    ,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$DbCatalog 
    ,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    #[ValidateScript({Validate-Country -Country $_ -DbInstance $DbInstance -DbCatalog $DbCatalog})] 
    [string]$Country
)

#move all logic from main script into here
#copy parameters from file's param definition, only add in validation
function RUN {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$DbInstance 
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$DbCatalog 
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateScript({Validate-Country -Country $_ -DbInstance $DbInstance -DbCatalog $DbCatalog})] 
        [string]$Country
    )
    process {
        "Script ran with Country $Country"
    }
}

#returns $true if the country is in the database's country table; otherwise false
function Validate-Country {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$DbInstance
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$DbCatalog
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$Country
    )
    process {
        $Country = $Country -replace "'","''"
        ((Execute-SQLQuery -DbInstance $DbInstance -DbCatalog $DbCatalog -Query "select top 1 1 x from dbo.Country where Name = '$Country'") | Measure-Object | Select -ExpandProperty Count) -gt 0
    }
}

function Execute-SQLQuery {
    #...
}

RUN @PSBoundParameters #remember to handle default parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808973/parameters-with-default-value-not-in-psboundparameters
```

Comment: What a mess... it's unfortunate that this is the only non-inline solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it one script, you can all a function within the script.  What I mean is something like this:

```
    Function fun1 {
       <code>
       }

    Function fun2 {
       <code>
       }

    Function fun3 {
       Param (
          Validatescript({
                  fun1
                  })$Param1
           )
        <code>
        }

    #start executing code
    fun3
```

This will enable you to run your script from a single file but also have your function as apart of your script validation.  Is it pretty? No.  Does it work? Yes.  I have done this several times in the past and has worked great.  The only thing you need to keep in mind is your script scoping with variables.

Comment: Can't do this while using the `param` keyword at the beginning of the script like the OP has.

Comment: Correct, it would require the modification the code but it breaks down to what the OP wants?  I just saw that having it in a single file would be easier on him versus having a script call a script.  Completely up to OP, just offering a different point of view.

Comment: Thanks @POSHGeek; per Matt's comments I'm ideally after a solution for parameters on the file itself (though I didn't explicitly mention that in the question).  For parameters on functions, the order of the functions doesn't matter.